# Angular 4 All Input with Value to Array

Tags: arrays, angular, list

I have a Question. I have an Array of Products in an Array with an Input Value.

[Productlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TGyh.jpg)

```
 <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
                      <div class="row_accordion">
                        <div class="row">
                          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                            <br>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">Blechdicke: 1,00 mm</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12"> Zulassungsnummer: Z-9.1-757</div>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div class="row">
                              <div class="artikelheader col-lg-2 col-xl-2">Menge</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader2 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">Art.Nr.</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader2 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">Größe</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-right">kg/ME</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader1 offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-right">ME</div>
                              <div class="artikelheader1 offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 offset-xl-1 col-xl-1 text-right">Preis/ME</div>  
                            </div>
                            <table class="table">
                          <tr class="artikel" *ngFor="let n of nagelplatten; index as i; odd as isOdd; even as isEven" 
                          [ngClass]="{ odd: isOdd, even: isEven }" >

                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-2 col-xl-2"><span><input  #qty><div *ngIf="n.ME > 1;then karton else stueck"></div></span><ng-template #karton> Karton</ng-template>
                            <ng-template #stueck> Stück</ng-template></div>
                            <div class="artikel col-sm-5 col-lg-1 col-xl-1">{{ n.PKArtikelID }}</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-sm-5 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">{{ n.Groesse }}</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-sm-5 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-right">{{ n.Gewicht | number: '1.4-4' }}</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-sm-5 offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 col-xl-1 text-right">{{ n.ME }}</div>
                            <div class="artikel col-sm-5 offset-lg-1 col-lg-1 offset-xl-1 col-xl-1 text-right">{{ n.Preis | number: '1.4-4'}}</div>  
                          </div>
                            <button [disabled]="qty.length == 1" (click)="addItemToCart(n.PKArtikelID, qty.value)">Add to cart</button>
                          </tr>
                        </table>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </ng-template>
```

So now we can I make a Button how looks in all Input Field with a Value and add it to a new Array?

Can anybody helps me?

THx

Comment: Please share your code. Are you using ReactiveForms or TemplateForms. Are you using for your Products a FormArray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain better and post the code you have?

Maybe I didn't get correctly but I think you need to use a *ngFor to loop through all the product also assigning a index.

```
<div *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index">
    // product info here //
    <button (click)="onAdd(i)">Add to new array</button>
</div>
```

When you click the button you pass the index of the item selected and you can push it into a new array or do all the array operations you want.
(products should be your array containing all the product info)

Comment: That works only for one product or? i would add all inputs with an Value.

Comment: if you store your products info in the products array, this code will generate the same template for each element, including a button

Comment: Have you an Example for me with the function?

Comment: Try this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvv6af?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts   In the example you will see that you have a list of products with a button and when you click it the selected products will be added in the new array. you can see it in the console

Comment: Ok, thanks, i see it. That is was I have. But we can I do this with 1 Button for all Inputs that has a Value. So I have 100 Products and I add by 10 a Quota and i clIck the Button and the add this 10 Products in an array. Thx

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xvv6af?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts in this example there is only one button. if the quantity is > 0 then it add the product to the cart. of course you need to replace the 'quantity' with your input value

Comment: Thx for the Example. We can I get the name from the Input Name in the Function? That is my last question

Comment: Has anybody a Tipp for my last Question

Comment: You need to create a local reference in the input field that you get with ViewChild in the component ts. Look the example. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxxtmd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts In this way you can get the text of the input field and pass into a variable

Comment: Hello. i become always this Error "Property 'nativeElement' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'."

Comment: Hello. So it works but when I add a Value to 1 Input than he did all of my Inputs to the function. So must I add an Index to the Input or what must I do.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxxtmd?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts u need to pass the value of the input and the index. I used the (keyup) but is not the best solution, you can find other events associated to the input

Comment: Hello. Thx for the Answer. Did you have a Tip what for the event is better for the (keyup) thx

Comment: You can try "focusout" in angular. The javascript is onfocusout